# convert a MQLONG value to string in c++

Tags: c++, printf, ibm-mq

How can I print a IBMMQ MQLONG value in c++ code. It gives a segmentation fault when I try to print

```
printf("Queue Persistance-> %s\n ", pMsgDesc -> Persistence );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The persistence field in the MQMD is not a string. You are telling printf to treat it as a string with the %s. In your question you do appear to be aware that it is an MQLONG though. Try using %d instead of %s.